# How to get Facebook status updates which are in english

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working in facebook Graph API. I want to get all status updates of a particular page which are only in English language. 
Is there any "lang" kind of parameters are there in Graph API...?? 
Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Run it through a language guessing service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "lang" param.

One thing I would try is trying to guess the language.
There are special Algorithms for different lanugages.

BTW: you can try out different kind of requests easilywith the api graph explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer